# mouse up - click outside of Div not working on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mouseup

I use the following to hide a div and ovelay div when clicking outside a form.

The following javascript is:

```
$(document).mouseup(function (e)
{
  var container = $("#feedbackform");
  var overlay = $("#overlay");

  if (!container.is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the container...
    && container.has(e.target).length === 0) // ... nor a descendant of the container
  {
    $('#feedbackform').fadeOut('fast'),
    $('#overlay').fadeOut('fast');
  }
});
```

This works fine on a desktop but not on touch mobile devices.

Im guessing its to do with mouseup, any suggestions?

Craig.

Answer (score 0):

Classic events won't work exactly the same on mobile devices (except some events such as 'click' which is quite the same).

So now you have some mobile specific events named `touch events` : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Touch_events

So touchend is probably the one you want to use :

```
$(document).on('mouseup touchend', function (e){

[...]

});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This event seems to fire after i click the button. I have an a link that has a function onclick to show the overlay and div. However when clicking this button they show but fadeOut straight away...